# JAVA FX - Create observableHashMap inside fxml

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

How can I write hashMap inside an fxml. I tried like this, but my IDE doesn't recognize the "entry" tag name. This must create a `Map<String, Integer>`

```
<FXCollections fx:factory="observableHashMap">
    <entry>
        <String fx:value="Vandaag" />
        <Integer fx:value="1"/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <String fx:value="Deze week" />
        <Integer fx:value="7"/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <String fx:value="Deze maand" />
        <Integer fx:value="31"/>
    </entry>
</FXCollections>
```

Answer (score 4):

Defining as

```
<FXCollections fx:factory="observableHashMap">
    <foo>123</foo>
    <bar>456</bar>
</FXCollections>
```

works. However you loose the type safety and may not able to define a space separated key like

```
<kung foo>123</kung foo>
```

So defining the map in controller seems more appropriate.

Comment: Passerby, you might have to add `<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>` to your FXML by hand—my IDE wouldn't do it for me.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much about maps in the introduction to FXML. However, you can do something like this: (in fxml)

```
<Group fx:id="mapWrapper">
   <properties Vandaag="1" Deze_week="7" Deze_maand="31" />
</Group>
```

Then in your controller class you can have:

```
@FXML
private Group mapWrapper;

private ObservableMap map;

public void initialize() {
   // the properties object is backed up by observable hash map
   map = mapWrapper.getProperties();

   // do something with the map
   map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value));
}
```

prints the following:

```
Deze_maand:31
Vandaag:1
Deze_week:7
```

It probably isn't exactly what you wanted but it works